# Adding custom look-control using setAttribute

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe, virtual-reality, webvr

I have created a custom look-controls and I want to add it to the scene using 'setAttribute(componentName, data)' but I don't know what to fill in parameters. Any ideas ?

Here is my attempt:

```
var skyImage = document.querySelector('#sky') as HTMLImageElement;
var aScene = document.querySelector("a-scene");
  if(skyImage.complete){
      if(skyImage.width/2 == skyImage.height){
  let camera = document.createElement('a-camera');
  camera.setAttribute('new-controls', 'true');
  aScene.appendChild(camera);
```

for the custom look-controls, I took the same code, just limited the rotation to the Y-axis and renamed it to new-controls.

Comment: It'd be easier for everybody to see what you're looking to do if you include some code.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Comment: show your look-controls code

Comment: @Mav I have added my attempt

Comment: @hosseinsedighian The look-controls the same with few edits, nothing wrong with it. The problem is when attaching the component to an entity to the scene using setAttribute

Answer (score 1):

You either need to specify the property you want to change:

```
el.setAttribute('mycomponent', 'someproperty', value)
```

or, if you want to attach the component with default values:

```
el.setAttribute('mycomponent', '')
```